# How to establish one to many relationship in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a bit confused while establishing one to many relationship in a SQL Server database. I'm not able to figure out how to create multiple tables and put data for this one to many relationship

Comment: Google it. [First result](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56738/one-to-one-one-to-many-table-relationships-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Did you try anything? Research?

Answer (score 2):

Creating the tables and defining the relationship:

```
create table the_one_entity
(
  id integer primary key, 
  some_data varchar(100)
);

create table the_many_entity
( 
  id             integer primary key, 
  the_one_id     integer not null, 
  some_more_data varchar(100),
  -- this establishes the relationship
  foreign key fk_one_to_many (the_one_id)  
     references the_one_entity (id)
);
```

The relationship is defined through the foreign key column `the_one_id` that references the primary key of `the_one_entity`

How to put data in.

First insert the rows for the "one" entity:

```
insert into the_one_entity 
  (id, some_data)
values 
  (1, 'First Thing'),   
  (2, 'Second Thing');
```

Then insert the rows for the related entity:

```
insert into the_many_entity
  (id, the_one_id, some_more_data)
values
  (1, 1, 'First detail for the First Thing'),
  (2, 1, 'Second detail for the First Thing'),
  (3, 1, 'Third detail for the First Thing'),
  (4, 2, 'First detail for the Second Thing'),
  (5, 2, 'Second detail for the Second Thing');
```